# What are the valid options for unit of measure when using the Amazon MWS feed api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Trying to upload a product using the Amazon mws feed api and my request is getting rejected. The error message from Amazon says I need to specify the unit of measure but I can't find the valid options for unitOfmeasure anywhere in the schema amazon publishes.

This is my body I am sending to Amazon:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<AmazonEnvelope>
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A326GY9JGCP2ET</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>cpa56309</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>UPC</Type>
                <Value>7426895714885</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Maximum Comfort CPAP Headgear Universal Replacement Strap for Masks * 4-Point Connection Works for Most All Nasal &amp; Full-face Sleep apnea Masks - Sleep Apnea, Anti-Snoring Equipment</Title>
                <Brand>wiser Innovations</Brand>
                <Description>This is a &lt;b>bold&lt;/b> test</Description>
                <BulletPoint>MORE COMFORT-Super comfortable, ultra soft, no-irritation neoprene strap</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>MORE COMFORT-Super comfortable, ultra soft, no-irritation neoprene strap</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>MORE COMFORT-Super comfortable, ultra soft, no-irritation neoprene strap</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>MORE COMFORT-Super comfortable, ultra soft, no-irritation neoprene strap</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>MORE COMFORT-Super comfortable, ultra soft, no-irritation neoprene strap</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency='USD'>22</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Wiser</Manufacturer>
                <SearchTerms>MORE COMFORT-Super comfortable, ultra soft, no-irritation neoprene strap</SearchTerms>
                <ItemType>cpap-accessories</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HealthMisc>
                            <UnitCount unitOfMeasure='1'>1</UnitCount>
                        </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                </Health>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

This is the schema definition for uploading misc health products for unitcount

```
            <xsd:element name="UnitCount" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="xsd:decimal">
                            <xsd:attribute name="unitOfMeasure" type="StringNotNull"
                                use="required"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
```

Anyone know where to find the options for unitOfMeasure? I have tried Individual and Box.

Comment: Your question saved by enormous time. Thanks. I was nowhere able to understand that I have to provide unit count in Health Misc. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think unitOfMeasure attribute should store any string representing a measure. For example `GR` which is gram. Or `Fl Oz` which is Fluid Ounces.

Comment: Have you seen a list (schema def) for this? I can't find it. I tried box, pkg, etc.

Comment: Type is `StringNotNull` so any of box or pkg should work as well... Not sure what is wrong if it is not working. But all the other types of measures are described here https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/amzn-base.xsd